# With launchctl 2, how can I infer the domain from a service that is already running on macOS >= 10.10?

Tags: macos, launchctl

`launchctl` 2 takes a specifier which indicates the target domain. According to the manual of the command, this specifier may take one of the following forms:

- `system/[service-name]`
- `user/<uid>/[service-name]`
- `login/<asid>/[service-name]`
- `gui/<uid>/[service-name]`
- `pid/<pid>/[service-name]`

The `launchctl list` command is now deprecated and replaced (I guess) by the `launchctl print` command. The later requires a domain-target or service-target as input.

1. Are there ONLY those five domains, or there can be more ?
2. If yes, how can I list all the domains in my system ?
3. **How do I infer the domain from a service that is already running ?**

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding `launchd` has a single domain, the `system` domain which itself has two subdomain types `user` and `pid`.

- `com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system`.
- `com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.<uid>`
- `com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.<pid>`:

To see all subdomains of the system domain:<sup>1</sup>

```
$ launchctl print system | awk '/^\t*subdomains/,/^\t*}/'
subdomains = {
  com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.systemstats.1142
  com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.softwareupdated.738
  com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501
  ...
}
```

My further interpretation is that if a user account is a regular user account *and* the user is currently logged into the graphical user interface then the user domain will have a user login subdomain for that user account.

```
$ launchctl print user/$(id -u) | awk '/^\tsubdomains/,/^\t}/'
subdomains = {
  com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.104157.Aqua
}
```

My further interpretation is that if that subdomain exists then `login/<asid>` and `gui/<uid>` can be used to access the services within that subdomain.

Either using the UID:

```
$ launchctl print user/$(id -u) | awk '/^\tservices/,/^\t}/'
services = {
61949   (pe)    com.apple.tonelibraryd
    0      -    com.apple.accounts.dom
  421      -    com.apple.distnoted.xpc.agent
...
}
```

Or alternatively the ASID (audit session identifier):

```
$ ASID=$(id -A | awk -F"=" '/asid/ {print $2}')
$ launchctl print login/$ASID | awk '/^\tservices/,/^\t}/'
```

There doesn't seems to be an official way to retrieve the domains that a service is currently registered in, but using `launchctl dumpstate` could be an approach.<sup>2</sup>

```
$ launchctl dumpstate | awk '/^com.apple.AVKit.OutputDeviceMenuService/,/^}/' | grep domain
domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.photoanalysisd.79837
domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Spotlight.79609
domain = com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Finder.79572
```

Wrapping that into a Bash function and adding it to `~/.bashrc`:

```
function launchctl_domains () {
  SERVICE="$1"
  launchctl dumpstate | awk "/^$SERVICE/,/^}/" | awk -F"=" '/domain/ {print $2}' | awk '{$1=$1;print}'
}
export -f launchctl_domains
```

A service in multiple PID domains:

```
$ launchctl_domains com.apple.AVKit.OutputDeviceMenuService
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.photoanalysisd.79837
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Spotlight.79609
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.Finder.79572
```

A service in multiple user domains:

```
$ launchctl_domains com.apple.tonelibraryd
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.501
com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.user.0
```

A service in a login user/GUI domain:

```
$ launchctl_domains com.apple.accountsd
com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.domain.501.104157.Aqua
```

---

<sub>1. Be aware that parsing the output of `launchctl print` is strongly discouraged in the man page of [`launchctl`](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/launchctl.1.html)</sub>

<sub>2. Documented  in `launchctl help`, it appears that the output is [truncated after 20 MB](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425542/launchctl-dumpstate-wont-give-full-dump)</sub>

<sub>Everything tested on macOS Catalina 10.15.7</sub>

<sub>I'm aware that the question was asked some time ago, but hopefully it can shed some light on the topic for others.</sub>